# Need assistance to remove outdated =* join operator from SQL 2005 query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Following query no longer compatible in SQL2012 and above. Need assistance to convert.

```
select distinct po.name , sc.name, sc2.name
from sysobjects fo, sysobjects po, sysforeignkeys fk, sysobjects oo
    , syscolumns sc, sysreferences ref, syscolumns sc2
where fo.xtype = 'F' and oo.name = @tab_name
  and po.id = fo.parent_obj and fo.id = fk.constid and oo.id = fk.rkeyid
  and sc.id = po.id and ref.constid = fk.constid and sc.colid = ref.fkey1
  and sc2.id =* po.id and sc2.colid =* ref.fkey2;
```

Comment: Where's the `=*`?

Comment: Apologies for the typos, the query has been edited and corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=*`'s point here is to give results even when no record can be found for `sc2`. Therefore, that's what absolutely needs to be turned into a `left join`:

```
select distinct po.name , sc.name, sc2.name
from (sysobjects fo, sysobjects po, sysforeignkeys fk, sysobjects oo
    , syscolumns sc, sysreferences ref)
left join syscolumns sc2
  on sc2.id = po.id and sc2.colid = ref.fkey2
where fo.xtype = 'F' and oo.name = @tab_name
  and po.id = fo.parent_obj and fo.id = fk.constid and oo.id = fk.rkeyid
  and sc.id = po.id and ref.constid = fk.constid and sc.colid = ref.fkey1;
```

For readability, do prefer to rewrite the rest of the old-style cross joins into inner joins as well though. You've already seen that the old-style syntax is too hard to understand.

Comment: by highlighting the query and opening the query editor, it convert the cross-join to inner join as below. Do you think I can trust the conversion by SSMS?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT po.name, sc.name AS Expr1, sc2.name AS Expr2
FROM sys.sysobjects AS fo INNER JOIN
sys.sysobjects AS po ON fo.parent_obj = po.id INNER JOIN
sys.sysforeignkeys AS fk ON fo.id = fk.constid INNER JOIN
sys.sysobjects AS oo ON fk.rkeyid = oo.id INNER JOIN
sys.syscolumns AS sc ON po.id = sc.id INNER JOIN
sys.sysreferences AS ref ON fk.constid = ref.constid AND sc.colid = ref.fkey1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.syscolumns AS sc2 ON po.id = sc2.id AND ref.fkey2 = sc2.colid
WHERE 
(fo.xtype = 'F') AND (oo.name = @tab_name)

Comment: @ybou If all the tables and all the conditions are there (I haven't checked), then yes, you can trust it, as the join order doesn't make any difference for inner joins.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query --

```
SELECT DISTINCT po.NAME
    ,sc.NAME
    ,sc2.NAME
FROM sysobjects fo
    ,sysobjects po
    ,sysforeignkeys fk
    ,sysobjects oo
    ,syscolumns sc
    ,sysreferences ref
    ,syscolumns sc2
WHERE fo.xtype = 'F'
    AND oo.NAME = @tab_name
    AND po.id = fo.parent_obj
    AND fo.id = fk.constid
    AND oo.id = fk.rkeyid
    AND sc.id = po.id
    AND ref.constid = fk.constid
    AND sc.colid = ref.fkey1
    AND sc2.id = Null -- sc2.id = * po.id 
    AND sc2.colid = Null -- sc2.colid = * ref.fkey2
```

Because,

```
*= Left Outer Join 

=* Right Outer Join
```

And in above query are trying to achieve the same by searching for Ids which are Nulls.

I hope it works.

Comment: It should be painfully obvious that this is not going to give any results.